# wcf get method - how to bind to view model?

Tags: c#, wcf

This is what I have in the service contract:

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
           BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
[OperationContract]
string HelloWorld(HelloWorldViewModel vm);
```

where `HelloWorldViewModel` has properties `X` and `Y`.

If I do `localhost/webservices/HelloWorld?X=1&Y=2`, and set a breakpoint in the `HelloWorld` method, vm will be null. It does not automatically bind the passed-in query string params into a view model object.

Am I missing something? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you described is implemented specifically in [ASP.NET MVC model binding](http://weblogs.asp.net/nmarun/archive/2010/02/25/asp-net-mvc-model-binding.aspx).

If you want to pass a complex object to a REST service operation using the [WCF Web Programming Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412172.aspx), you'll have to **include it in its serialized form in the body of an HTTP POST request**.

In your case, based on the attributes placed on the `HelloWorld` service operation, the request's payload should look something like this (note that XML namespace declarations are omitted):

```
<HelloWorld>
    <vm>
        <X>1</X>
        <Y>2</Y>
    </vm>
</HelloWorld>
```

**Related resources:**

- [WebMessageBodyStyle Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.web.webmessagebodystyle%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

`vm == null` is correct. It have to be sent as media parameter to your uri to be non null.

To get your parameters try to inspect:
`WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.UriTemplateMatch.QueryParameters["X"]`
or `...QueryParameters["Y"]`

Answer (score 0):

WCF [WebGet] operations only support primitive types by default. If you want to add support for other types, you can either create a type converter or a new `QueryStringConverter` that supports your type. You can find more information at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/08/09/wcf-extensibility-querystringconverter.aspx.

Another option would be to pass the parameter in the request body, but that would mean using a HTTP verb other than "GET", since GET requests cannot have body.